# How to speed up multiBarChart transitions?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, transition, nvd3.js

I'm using the nvd3.js multibar chart (http://nvd3.org/), and everything is great other than the speed of the transition from grouped bar chart to stacked bar chart, which is too slow for my tastes. The lack of nvd3.js documentation is causing me some pain, and I can't figure out how to reduce the duration of these (really cool) transitions. anybody know how? Thankee, SO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a method `transitionDuration()` to set this, i.e. you can do

```
chart.transitionDuration(100);
```

to speed it up from the default of 250.

Comment: For perpetuity, the transitionDuration property was added in 1.1.10 beta, so I had to get the code from the git repo. The build on the nvd3 website is still at 1.0.0.